Looping Flextables into Word doc using Markdown in R
I am attempting to use for loops to generate and then print flextables into a Word doc using R Markdown
At first I was using print in the loop, and it returned something to the effect: "A flextable object: col_keys ..." and so on, where nothing was formatted and my tables were printed as if someone typed them. I saw David's solution from 2019:
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)

ft <- flextable(head(iris))
for(i in 1:3){
  cat("<w:p/>")## add this to add an empty  new paragraph between tables
  flextable::docx_value(ft)
}

but unfortunately when I ran this I got an error:
! 'docx_value' is not an exported object from 'namespace:flextable'

Quitting from lines 14-19 [unnamed-chunk-1] (Prac.Rmd)
Execution halted```


Something like that:
---
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
print_in_loop <- function(x) {
  tmp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
  writeLines(
    c("```{r echo=FALSE}",
      "x", "```", ""),
    tmp_file,
    useBytes = TRUE)
  
  z <- knitr::knit_child(input = tmp_file, envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE)
  cat(z, sep = '\n')
}

```


```{r results='asis'}
ft <- flextable(head(iris))
for(i in 1:3){
  cat("<w:p/>")## add this to add an empty  new paragraph between tables
  print_in_loop(ft)
}
```



